# Activity Indicator not working when called from rootVC

Tags: ios, activity-indicator

I have a rootVC in which i have a view called loadingView and an activityIndicator in loadingView. The problem is that when i called the loadingView into another VC that inherit VC, the loadingView is nil...Does anybody know? Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: in rootVC the activityIndicator and view i made it from xib. PlaylistViewController [the inherited VC] the code is: [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.loadingView];

Comment: did you created `loadingView` in xib of `rootVC`? if yes it will be nil in its child view controller with xib for child view controller.

Comment: So the problem is you are added `loadingView` to the xib of parent `rootVC` here, and creating a child view controller instance with its own xib. So the parent xib is not loaded and `loadingView` will be nil. Either create `loadingView` programatically or use progress hud libraries.

Comment: yes.I di created from xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is you are added `loadingView` to the xib of parent `rootVC` here, and creating a child view controller instance with its own xib. So the parent xib is not loaded and `loadingView` will be nil. Either create `loadingView` programatically or use progress hud libraries.